# Exported service not injecting in my bundle in Spring Dynamic Modules

Tags: spring, osgi, osgi-bundle, spring-dm, dosgi

I am using Spring Dynamic Modules for the first time. I have tried to expose a service (simple listofValuesDAO Bean) through a bundle and am trying to inject it in another bundle to use the bean.
Below is configuration tag in osgi-context.xml of Bundle1 through which service was exposed:

```
 <osgi:service ref="listOfValuesDAO" auto-export="interfaces"/>
```

and I am trying to fetch it in Bundle2 through below tag in osgi-context.xml:

```
  <osgi:reference id="listOfValuesDAO" interface="com.dao.IListOfValuesDAO" />
```

The issue is that when I try to inject it in my bean in Bundle2 using below configuration:

```
 <bean id="exportServiceImpl" class="com.service.impl.ExportServiceImpl">
    <property name="listOfValuesDAO" ref="listOfValuesDAO"/>
</bean>
```

System throws below exception:

```
 Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-85"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exportServiceImpl' defined in URL [bundle://325.16:0/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: 

Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'listOfValuesDAO' of bean class [com.service.impl.ExportServiceImpl]: 

Bean property 'listOfValuesDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'listOfValuesDao'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

Below is property in my ExportServiceImpl Class:

```
public class ExportServiceImpl implements IExportService {
IListOfValuesDAO listOfValuesDao;
public void setListOfValuesDao(IListOfValuesDAO listOfValuesDao) {
    this.listOfValuesDao = listOfValuesDao;
}
public IListOfValuesDAO getListOfValuesDao() {
    return listOfValuesDao;
}
}
```

Could someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with case inconsistency: `listOfValuesDao` and `listOfValuesDAO` are different names.

You use the first version in the Service, and the second in the XML bean definition. Try:

```
<bean id="exportServiceImpl" class="com.service.impl.ExportServiceImpl">
    <property name="listOfValuesDao" ref="listOfValuesDao"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks David, it was a silly mistake of mine. Its working now. Thanks again.